# Imageresizer.net showing red dot in free version

Tags: imageresizer

I recently updated ImageResizer.NET to version 4.04 and a small red dot is now appearing on all the resized images. I understand this occurs if you don't have a paid for license but haven't entered the license key in the web.config. However, I am using the free version with no paid for plugins. According to the website, no license is required for the free version.

I have restarted the website and viewed different images so I don't think it's caching them.

Here is the output from resizer.debug:

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet          1/25/2016 10:52:33 AM

0 Issues detected:

Assembly use report: 

You do not seem to be using any plugins from (commerical/AGPL) editions.

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultSettings
ImageResizer.Plugins.TinyCache.TinyCachePlugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<plugins>
<add name="DefaultSettings" />
<add name="TinyCache" />
</plugins>
<defaultsettings explicitSizeScaleMode="Both" />
<clientcache minutes="1440" />
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi,
```

How do I get rid of this red dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `&crop=10,10,-10,10`, does the dot disappear?

If so, you've saved watermarked images to disk as originals. Perhaps you're using ImageResizer during upload or the storage process, and have unlicensed plugins for a *different* instance of `ImageResizer.Configuration.Config`? You can access the diagnostics page string from code - `GetDiagnosticsPage()` or write it to a file  - `WriteDiagnosticsTo(string path)` to assist with troubleshooting.

The code which creates the red dot registers itself as a plugin, `LicenseEnforcer`. That plugin is not present in the diagnostics page, which tells me that the application process serving you the diagnostics page is likely different from the one serving your images. That, or you are using a custom `Config` instance at runtime.

Comment: Adding the crop query string makes no difference.I'm using Chrome with the cache disabled to ensure I'm not seeing it cached on the client side. We use the recommended best-practice of re-sizing the images at run time rather than at upload time.

Comment: Can you provide URLs for the images and diagnostics page? If the domain is exactly the same you may omit that portion.

Comment: After some more investigation, I realized I was being thick. The images are served from a different domain and that domain was using paid plugins (which I've now removed). Thanks for you help Nathanael.

Comment: One thing I did find strange is that when TinyCache is enabled, I always get a blank image. Firefox reports that it is returning a 500 error somewhere. It's hosted on Azure but I don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: @user2981411 https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1749/Imagemagick.html  
It's also very slow. If you're paying for a server, you'll be wasting both time and money.